# Pyridine: Protic or Aprotic

Tags: aromatic-compounds, solvents, heterocyclic-compounds

I know pyridine is a polar aprotic solvent (owing to a permanent dipole generated), but if acidified it forms pyridinium cation. So, does it then function as polar protic solvent?

Comment: Pyridinium salts are generally solids. Are you refering to them as solvents in the molten state?

Comment: If you acidify pyridine with $\ce{HCl}$, for example, you form [pyridinium chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyridinium_chloride), which is a solid (m.p. $\pu{144 ^\circ{}C}$, same reference). Thus, at ambient conditions, it is not considered a solvent.  With a $pK_a$ around 5, it is about as (mildly) acidic as acetic acid, though.

Comment: [pKa of conjugate acid of pyridine is 5.2](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2017/04/18/basicity-of-amines-and-pkah/), while pKa of water is 7. If you could get so many pyridinium cations in liquid form, then theoretically yes, it would be a polar protic solvent.

Comment: Ad hoc, because of Waylander's comment: as an example, $\ce{py.HCl}$ may be molten, then used as a solvent, e.g., [2004OrgProcResDev670](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/op0499526).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the designation of a solvent as aprotic is based on the unmodified solvent molecule, which in the case of pyridine is aprotic.

Pyridine is not unique in terms of this question.  We would generally expect polar aprotic solvents such as DMSO to accept a proton at their negative charge centers (such as the oxygen in DMSO) given a suitable acid.  Such a reaction enables polar aprotic solvents to preferentially conduct solvated protons versus other ions via a mechanism similar to the [Grotthus mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotthuss_mechanism) in water.